# Theory of floating point math

Tags: group-theory, floating-point

We learn about groups, rings and fields in algebra - but floating point numbers (like `double` in many modern programming languages) do not form one of the above algebraic entities because they are not associative.

Is there an algebraic theory behind these numbers?

Comment: [Interval arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic) is somewhat related, but not an algebra and also does not have the specific granularity of floating point numbers included.

Comment: I think abstract algebra covers this subject. We have a set and operations defined on that set. Read about magma/groupoid.

Comment: You might be interested in section 4.2.2, "Accuracy of Floating Point Arithmetic" in The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 2, Seminumerical Algorithms,Third Edition,  by Donald Knuth.

Comment: @vasya: Thank you for the keywords. Do you know of a general sructure with two operations?

Comment: @gammatester: In my understanding, such structure is a ringoid. You may be interested in reading "Computer Arithmetic in Theory and Practice"
By Kulisch & Miranke